# Configuring Multiple Maven Repositories

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-2, maven-3, nexus

I have a SpringBoot project that uses maven and IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (a build automation tool used primarily for Java projects)
I have this `settings.xml` for maven but when I do a `mvn -U clean install`, only goes the the first repository to find the files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>C:/Users/sandro/.m2</localRepository>


  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <servers>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>TeamNexus1</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>TeamNexus1</name>          
      <url>http://benficiones.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>          
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>TeamNexus2</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>TeamNexus2</name>    
      <url>http://benficiones2.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>p1</id>
     <repositories>     
        <repository>
              <id>TeamNexus1</id>
            <name>TeamNexus1</name>      
            <url>http://benficiones.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>      
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>TeamNexus2</id>
            <name>TeamNexus2</name>   
                   <url>http://benficiones2.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
             <releases><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></releases>
             <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled><updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy></snapshots>
        </repository>
  </repositories>
</profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>p1</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined TeamNexus1 als `<mirrorOf>` everything. This means that any requests, to whatever repository they go, are redirected to TeamNexus1.

This is probably not what you want.

If you want to use the two repositories *in addition to* MavenCentral (which is implicitly configured), you can just remove the whole `<mirrors>` section.

Comment: With the solution proposed I have this error: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.0: 
Could not transfer artifact org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:pom:0.8.0 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.36.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Then you probably cannot directly connect to MavenCentral. Are the artifacts in one of the TeamNexus repositories?

Comment: indeed, I think so

Comment: Then only remove the second mirror and for the first, write `<mirrorOf>*,!TeamNexus2</mirrorOf>`

Comment: The previous comment is the best approach.   If you entirely remove the mirrors section then Maven will start using repository definitions from pom files, which will lead to problems.  Use "<mirrorOf>*,!TeamNexus2</mirrorOf>".